# Have we measured the rate at which Jupiter is shrinking?

Tags: measurements, jupiter

On most websites that I looked at, it says Jupiter is shrinking 2cm/year (for example [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter#Mass_and_size) and [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-Jupiter-shrinking-If-yes-why)).  However neither of these website say whether this rate is measurable (the latter says it is a theoretical prediction to answer why Jupiter is so "hot").

Is this rate *directly* measurable, (maybe by shooting a laser at Jupiter and measuring how long it takes to reflect)?  If it is not measurable yet, then is that completely outside of what we hope to achieve in the next 50 years?

Comment: Note: if you don't get good answers here, you might also want to try astronomy.stackexchange (that doesn't mean you should or have to try, the question is good and on topic here).

Comment: @Martin I thought [cross-posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu?rq=1) was considered bad, or did you mean I should ask for it to be migrated?

Comment: @StrategyThinker, Martin is just saying if you don't get an answer here you can try it somewhere else; for now, it's fine here.

Comment: Please can you provide a link(s) to your source(s).  It is difficult to comment on a claim when you don't identify who has made it.  Don't those sources explain how those estimates were measured?

Comment: @sammygerbil I have added some links.

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to measure the spectral changes in radiation emitted by jupiter(after absorption from the sun). Thereby grtting an idea for the rate o shrinking

Answer (score 1):

Considering the stormy nature of Jupiter's atmosphere, and the planet's vast size, no I don't think that kind of shrinkage rate is significant, and therefore not measurable.  Moreover, it is certainly not the kind of useful information which it is worth the effort trying to obtain.